# how to know my wiki edit count

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I want to know how many **wiki edits** I have done now So Is there any way to know how many **wiki edits** I have done till now ?

Comment: Worth to mention that all your edits so far (here on meta) except one were bad and/or invalid. You will soon be edit banned if you won't improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer..

When *mouse hover* on any of `tag` there is an option of `info`, just go to  `info` and see below :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Just go to any tag, click on the "learn more" link. On this page, at the right side of the page, you see stats, top answerers and also the count of tag wiki edits you've done.